# Trouble with sending input via RDP by all known ways

Tags: c#, rdp, mstsc

I write a little client using WinForms, C#, AxMsTscNotSafeForScripting tool, and I need to send Win+R on the VM(yes, I know, there's a way to launch app remotely without RunDialog, but I need to). 
I quickly found nice lib named `InputSimulator`, it simulates everything correctly on my main machine, but no effect on VM.

Actually, it can send the whole `string` into notepad, but when it deals with VirtualKeyCodes, nothing happens.
After drilling Google a bit deeper I found usage of `WindowsAPI.SendInput` with methods

`void PressKey(char ch, bool press) 
void KeyDown(ushort scanCode) 
void KeyUp(ushort scanCode)`.

`PressKey` is working with VM, but `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`, which I need, are incorrect. For example, 81 is ScanCode for "Q", but it prints "." in notepad, 82 is for "R", but I get "0" and I get nothing at all with 91, that's for Windows key.
If I press key with a keyboard, everything works, so problem isn't in KeyPreview, EnableWindowsKey, etc settings
Both systems are Win7, Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Even if my way is hopeless, what are another ways to send Win+R programmly to VM? Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not the *length* of your question that's the problem, it's the complete lack of organization.  Please edit.  You also will want to use backticks (``) around code to make it appear correctly.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hope now it looks better, it's my 1st question here, thanks for your advice, now I'd be glad to have some answers if possible

Comment: That is *amazingly* better.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `PressKey` is working is that you're supplying an ASCII `char`, which it expects.

The reason `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` are not working is that [you're still supplying an ASCII value](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg), but these expect a scan code.  Scan codes are not the same as ASCII codes.  82 (0x52) is not `"R"` in any of [the common scancode tables](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-10.html#ss10.6) -- in both Table 2 and 3 it is NumPad 0, which is consistent with your observed behavior.

You need to use [`MapVirtualKey(Ex)`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mapvirtualkeyex) to translate your ASCII code or virtual key code into a scan code.

It looks like `"R"` is 0x13 (in both Table 2 and 3), but the WinKey has a different code in every table, so you should not hard-code the value but get it at runtime using `MapVirtualKeyEx`.

Comment: Thank you very much! So strange I used VK-table instead of such. However, I still doing something wrong and still no winkey arrived to VM

Comment: @Amateur: What did `MapVirtualKeyEx` tell you is the scan code for the Windows key?

Comment: @Amateur: `5B` does appear in that table for the Windows key... but as `E0,5B` (an extended key).  Try sending either `0xE05B` or sending two keys, `0xE0` then `0x5B`.